# Infinite composition of continuous functions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, terminology, continuity

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions and define $F_n:= f_n\circ \dots\circ f_1$.  Then $F_n$ is continuous.  However, the pointwise limit need not be (consider Mateusz's example of
$$
f_n = \frac{\sqrt{2} x}{\sqrt{1 + 4 x^2}} \qquad F_n \to \operatorname{sign}(x) 
$$
the sign function).

In general, what can be said about the limits of an iterated function system?  Are such functions studied and if so what are they called?

All I figure at the moment is that they must necessary be of [Baire 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function) type.

Comment: The iterates of $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{2}\,x}{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}$ seem to converge to the sign function.

Comment: Didn't the original version ask for continuity of the limit? And, in any case, it *does* hint what the structure of all possible limits is.

Comment: Oh no, I don't expect/want the limit to be continuous.  Either way, I updated the question (also using your example) and I think what I'm looking for are limits of iterated function systems (which te earlier formulation was a special case of).

Comment: (1/2) For the iterates of the same function (as in the initial version of this question), there are entire [books](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0084762) on dynamics in one dimension, and it is pretty easy to see that all potential limits are piecewise constant nonincreasing functions with the property $f(I) \subseteq I$ for any maximal interval $I$ on which $f$ is constant (and we allow $I$ to be a degenerate interval $\{x\}$).

Comment: (2/2) On the other hand, for an arbitrary sequence of continuous functions $f_n$, the situation is much more complicated. My guess would be: all possible limits are of the form $f(x) = g(h(x))$ with $h$ continuous and $g$ monotone, but that is just an uneducated guess.

Comment: In the example given I think that $F_n$ tends to $\mathrm{sign}/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: There is an introduction to infinite compositions of complex functions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_compositions_of_analytic_functions

Comment: Thanks, but I have read this article (its a good first stop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you’re searching for names: there is a rich literature on *discrete non-autonomous dynamical systems* generated by an infinite family of continuous maps. Here "non-autonomous" means of course that the map you apply depends on the order of iteration, which is exactly your subject.

For instance:

1. Cánovas, J. S. (2006). On ω-limit sets of non-autonomous discrete systems. Journal of Difference Equations and Applications, 12(1), 95-100.
   ISO 690
2. Shao, H., Chen, G., & Shi, Y. (2020). Some criteria of chaos in non-autonomous discrete dynamical systems. Journal of Difference Equations and Applications, 26(3), 295-308.
3. Sharma, P., & Raghav, M. (2015). Dynamics of nonautonomous discrete dynamical systems. arXiv preprint arXiv:1512.08868.

You can find a lot more, I suggested those just to make it clear which kind of name/keywords can be useful for you. You'll find lots of results on interval maps, real maps and on more general spaces. It all depends on which specific questions you want to address.

Good news for you: you don't have to consider Baire class 1 functions in their full glory, since given a sequence $\{F_n\}$ of continuous functions which converges pointwise, the functions $f_n$ solving the countable set of functional equations $$F_{n}(x)=f_n(F_{n-1}(x)), \ n\ge 2,$$ even when they exist, aren't necessarily continuous. So you're exploring a (topologically small, I guess) portion of Baire class 1 maps.